# What is the content view of the activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In this statement what is the meaning of content?

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
```

This is from one of the Android Developers fragment examples.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is the `ViewGroup` to which you attach the fragment. For example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This code would replace whatever is in the `fragment_container` view with the `newFragment`.

```
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
```